# Custom typing effect going crazy in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to have a custom typing effect in a div. I've got 2 pages `people` and `jobs` So the flow goes this way,

- I pass a variable `startTyping`(boolean) to another component `RenderTb`.
- If it is true, I want the animation to happen, else it shouldn't do anything.
- Currently the issues I see are

  - In the Jobs page, I'm not setting the `startTyping` flag and in my RenderTb component it is set to `false` by default. But still the animation continues on that page even.
  - On first load the animation works fine on the people page, but when I switch to jobs page and back to the people page, the animation goes crazy.

Can someone please let me know where I'm going wrong?

Here is my working code. https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-heisenberg-hv6rys

Comment: Please put a [mre] _in the question_.

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **useRef** instead of document.querySelector in RenderTB.

You should also clear the timeout, so it won’t affect the code in another route.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import {
  useEffect,
  useState,
  useRef
} from "react";
export interface typeProps {
  head: string;
  startTyping ? : boolean;
}
const RenderTb = ({
  head,
  startTyping = false
}: typeProps) => {
  var i = 0;
  const [queryPrompts, setQueryPrompts] = useState < string[] > ([]);
  let timer: Number;
  const p = useRef < HTMLElement | null > (null);

  / ---- Code --/


  useEffect(() => {
    / ---- 
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }
  }, [queryPrompts]);

  return ( <
    >
    <
    h2 > {
      head
    } < /h2> <
    p ref = {
      p
    }
    className = "demo" > < /p> <
    />
  );
};

export default RenderTb;
```